# Handler Method Invocation

Tags: c#, ihttphandler

I am creating one handler for processing image. When i try to request the url `http://localhost/ProcessImage.ashx` the `ProcessRequest` is getting invoked by default. This is not a `Constructor`. But how it is getting called by default?

```
public class ProcessImage : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: When an HTTP handler is requested, ASP.NET calls the ProcessRequest method on the appropriate handler. The handler's ProcessRequest method creates a response, which is sent back to the requesting browser. As with any page request, the response goes through any HTTP modules that have subscribed to events that occur after the handler has run. Refer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227675(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @DotNetMirror, Hi can u post this as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look at the [ASP.NET Application Lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx). For handlers (IHttpHandler), the implementation of the method ProcessRequest is called whenever you access/request for the handler.